# Hosts File (Kinda) Doesn't Work

Tags: hosts-file

Im having some trouble with my host file..

If I change the IP for a domain it and flush the DNS I still get the old site, but if I set the IP to 000.000.000.000 I get an error, like I should.

This is my current hosts file:

```
#
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
119.47.114.165  home.m2pp.co.nz
```

But home.m2pp.co.nz still uses the new IP: 173.236.119.234
The only time I see a change is when I use 000.000.000.000 and I get the message "Google Chrome's connection attempt to home.m2pp.co.nz was rejected"

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably tried this but I find I usually have to completely close my browser in addition to flushing the DNS cache

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Nope, I cleared the browser cache. I think the browser is picking up the changes because when I enter 000.000.000.000 it gives me the error. But for some reason other IP's don't seem to work..